# The C pointer array subscript, cannot start from 0

Tags: c

```
int main(void){
    char *p[]={};
    char *temp=NULL;
    int end=0;
    char y_n=0;
    int w=0; //pointer array subscript 
    int gc=1;

while(true){
    printf("enter content:\n");
    while((end=getchar())!='\n'){
        if(gc==1){
            p[w]=(char *)calloc(gc,sizeof(char));
            strcat(p[w],(char *)&end);
        }
        else{
            temp=(char *)realloc(p[w],gc*sizeof(char));
            if(temp==NULL){
                printf("memory fail\n");
                break;
            }
            p[w]=temp;
            /*here temp and p[w] reference same address
            so temp pointer set value is NULL break reference address
            so temp pointer not use free function.
            if temp pointer use free function,at the same time clean p[w] in memory address.
            */
            temp=NULL;
            strcat(p[w],(char *)&end);
        }
        gc++;
    }
    printf("p[%d]:%s\n", w,p[w]);
    gc=1;
    w++;

    printf("continue y or n:");
    scanf("%c",&y_n);
    if(y_n=='n'){
        break;
    }
    getchar();
}
printf("w:%d\n", w);


    /*test*/
    while((--w)>=0){
        printf("p[%d]:%s\n", w,p[w]);
        free(p[w]);
        p[w]=NULL;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

inital value w=0，
cycle to p[w=0]  error:Segmentation fault (core dumped)

---

inital value w=1 start

### cycle p pointer array no problem

why?
no inital value pointer array,subscript can not start at 0？

Comment: `char *p[]={};` is not valid C. You need at least one initialiser inside the braces.

Comment: @alk Yes, but not one of the good ones, IMO. I bet the OP didn't expect a 0-sized array here.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I agree. However, I was fooled by my standard make: gcc (4.4.5) fails, it's a clang extension.

Comment: @alk My gcc-4.7.2 accepts it without complaint in default mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *p[]={};
```

is not valid C, but it is a GNU extension (also accepted by clang), hence gcc accepts the code.

However, what it does is declare a 0-sized array `p` of `char*`s. So using any `p[w]` invokes undefined behaviour. Whether it crashes or not depends on your luck. If you are lucky, it crashes always.

You need to declare `p` with the required size. If you don't know how many elements you need, make it a `char**` and `malloc`/`realloc` it.

Comment: The interessting thing is that if I pass `char * p[] = {}` to clang it produces the same as `char * p[1] = {0}`.

Comment: My clang makes it a zero-sized array, like gcc: `extension.c:4:17: warning: zero size arrays are an extension`. Did you perchance put the `char *p[] = {};` at file scope?

Comment: No difference if at file or function scope. I get `warning: zero size arrays are an extension [-pedantic]` but code as mentioned using clang version 1.1 (Debian 2.7-3).

Comment: @alk `printf("%zu\n", sizeof p);`? Prints 0 for me.

Comment: `(gdb) p sizeof p` gives me `$1 = 8`.

Comment: I didn't see it before: clang-1.1 - I have 3.2, probably the behaviour changed in the meantime.

Comment: Same for `char *p[0] = {};`, btw.

Comment: thank you @DanielFischer@alk
    
    char *p[]={}  in program,although it is the goal to reach the corresponding,but really is not good way.

Comment: test output:when w=1,
    
    enter content:
    
    aa
    
    p[1]:aa
    
    continue y or n:y
    
    enter content:
    
    dd
    
    p[2]:dd
    
    continue y or n:u
    
    enter content:
    
    dd
    
    p[3]:dd
    
    continue y or n:y
    
    p[...]
    p[....]
    p[....]
    
    continue y or n:n
    break;
    
    cycle output p pointer array:
    
    p[1]:aa
    
    p[2]:dd
    
    p[3]:dd
    p[..]:..
    p[..]:..
    p[..]:..
    p[..]:..
    -------------------------